# Highly parallel deque

Tags: c++, boost, std

Is there an implementation (boost or otherwise) of a highly parallel deque? In particular, I want to be able to say things like this (pseudocode):

```
parallel.for(deque.erase, list<locations>);
```

In other words, in parallel remove all the items passed in a e.g. List of locations in the deque. At the same time, I don't want this operation to block other deletes or inserts that have nothing to do with this delete/insertion.

So for example, thread 1 could be (parallel) deleting items at locations 1,3,7,9, thread 2 (parallel) inserting into the deque (parallel insertions can be push_back and seem easy unless trying to insert into old erased locations), and thread three could be (parallel) deleting locations 2,4,8 [note that different thread erases never intersect erase locations]. Trying to erase an already erased location (holding a sentinel value) is an error. That probably means that locations are stateful until some compaction occurs (which requires a lock.) Erased locations could hold a sentinel value that says to other threads you can insert into me...So the interface may not be push_back, but push_available.

Thinking outloud, I realize that the deque **may** become fragmented and grow (memory leak) as push_backs don't fill erased values (?), but some sort of compaction seems possible eventually.

The paralell_deque should also allow locking where no insertions or deletions are allowed until the lock is removed. For example, when printing the state (contents) of the deque...

deque can have multiple strategy for implementation, and some may be more amenable than others to this sort of parallelism.

I also realize that this question might be too vague and get shot down before interesting answers are given.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your use of the word “deque”.  Normally, that data structure does not support insertions and deletions at random positions but only at either end.  Are you looking for a doubly linked list?  There are some lock free data structures in [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) but without knowing what operations you really require, it's hard to say whether any of them (maybe in combination) can fit your needs.

Comment: This question is a little strange because you generally do not want a dequeue if you're adding and subtracting from arbitrary locations, you want a list.  This question sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  There are [parallel queue implementations](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html), but they do not really work in the manner you are describing.

Comment: @QuestionC although the queues you link to specifically make all other operations on the queue block whenever modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you really want a node-based container (which doesn't invalidate iterators) but with contiguous storage.

I'd suggest constructing a linked-list on top of contiguously stored elements using Boost Intrusive.

However, before that, I'd live with the simplest data structure you can think of until you *do* know what exactly you want and why.